# Не работает директива AddDefaultCharset в .htaccess! Помогите! [ РЕШЕНО ]

Tags: html, .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно задать кодировку по умолчанию на всех страницах каталога через .htaccess.

Пишу туда:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Но ничего не работает. Также отображаются непонятные символы вместо нормального текста. Другие директивы отлично работают. То есть конфигурация Apache настроена правильно.

*Использую Open server.

*Кодировка .htaccess -- utf-8 без BOM.

Пожалуйста объясните, в чём проблема? Или подскажите другой вариант изменения кодировки (только через .htaccess!)

Comment: А текст у вас где лежит? В базе? При подключении к базе вы кодировку устанавливаете? В базе тексты читаются? В файлах? Кодировка файлов utf8?

Comment: Обычный html файл. Кодировка не utf-8, поэтому и хочу ее изменить. Но чтобы не перебирать все файлы использую AddDefaultCharset

Comment: Должен быть полный набор: 1 Сам контент в нужной кодировке 2 тэг meta, чтобы браузер не занимался угадыванием 3 настройка сервера (то, что вы делаете в .htaccess)

Comment: Так меняйте кодировку файла на utf8! Как вам apache ее может директивой-то сменить!? Он только заголовок выставляет.